# How to delete identical lines in my output files?

Tags: linux, bash, uniq

I have this script :

```
#!/bin/bash

ps -eo lstart,pid,cmd --sort lstart | while read line 2> /dev/null
        do
        if [ "$(date -d "${line::24}" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")" -gt "$(date -d "Thu Apr  7 00:55:38" "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S")" ] 2> /dev/null
        then echo "Date : $(date -d "${line::24}" "+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S") | PID & CMD : ${line:25:29}" >> process.log 2> /dev/null
        fi 2> /dev/null
        done

sort process.log | uniq > process.log

#sort process.log | uniq -u | tee process.log
```

My script runs automatically every 10 seconds, so I would like the identical lines to be deleted. As you can see, I tried with uniq but it doesn't work. I would like all lines in my file to be deleted if they are identical.

As I did, the second time the script is executed, there is nothing in the output file and I don't understand why.

I would also like nothing to be displayed in my terminal when the script runs. I used tee but when executing the uniq command, it returns an output in my terminal... How to remove it?

I thank you in advance for your help and wish you a good day
Thanks a lot

Comment: `sort process.log | uniq > process.log` You can't read and write from the same file at the same time.

Comment: Ok thank you, I think that's why it's not always working. Do you know how to make sure that my line is not duplicated when the script is re-executed?

Comment: `sort process.log | uniq >tempfile` `mv tempfile process.log`

Answer (score 0):

You should not parse `ps` output ever, especially not of `lstart`. Also, you are running date in the loop all the time, again and again.

I think something along this would be better to do:

```
some_date=$(date -d "Thu Apr  7 00:55:38" +%s)
now=$(date +%s)
how_much_time_ago=$(( now - some_date ))
ps -eo etimes,pid,cmd --sort etimes |
awk -v v="$how_much_time_ago" '$1 > v' |
while IFS=' ' read line etimes pid cmd; do
     printf "Date : %s | PID & CMD : %s %s\n" \
         "$(date -d "$((now - etimes))" "+%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")" \
         "$pid" "$cmd"
done |
sort |
uniq > process.log
```

Note that you can pipe the output of a `while .... done | stuff` loop to another thing normally. Instead of sprinkling `2>/dev/null` everywhere, try to actually solve the issue, not hide the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it help me a lot ! I make a parsing on ps because our teacher asked us that in the exercise, it doesn't really have a real purpose, it's rather to practice